# Show Sitename on Yoast SEO Title tag

Tags: plugins, title, seo, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I am using Yoast SEO plugin on a site.  Right now if a Post's Title is left empty in the metabox for a post, then the Title tag will output in this format...

```
%%title%% %%page%% %%sep%% %%sitename%%
```

Now if that same post does have a custom title text saved in it's meta field...then it shows only the text from the meta.

What I need to do is show `%%sitename%%` after the titlte text no matter what!

So even a title that is saved as `This is my title` the output on the HTML page will be...
 `This is my title - SITENAME`

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `wpseo_title` filter to read the  tag for your site title after WPSEO creates it, and if it's not there, add it on.

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_title', 'wpse137502_wpseo_title' );
function wpse137502_wpseo_title( $title ) {
    $site_title = get_bloginfo( 'name' );
    if ( ! strpos( $title, $site_title ) ) {
        $title .= " | " . $site_title;
    }
    return $title;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I wish Yoast had a checkbox option to always include the title template, when using custom titles (which essentially override the template).

Comment: Indeed. But the idea for the override is complete control. It shouldn't STILL add in stuff.